# How to generate own lazy module / chunk compatible with Angular 6+ AoT

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading

I'm using angular-cli to generate ng6/7 app (all related libs in recent/latest versions)  where I use webpack configuration via ngx-build-plus (extension for classis angular-cli devkit) where I use "externals" to exclude the libraries from final bundle (I want to share all platform libraries like angular, rxjs etc for all my individual micro apps)

As consequence - there is a limitation related to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11490

It means if I exclude @angular/core it stops to generate lazy module chunks. I can probably manually replace all "loadChildern" string occurences (if necessary) and replace them with some call to load file but...how can I generate compatible chunk / lazy module to be able load it in this way? Specifying new "entry" point in webpack config is not enough (it generates bundle which does not include all stuff, e.g. html) Should I create totally separate webpack config? Will that be compatible with previously generated bundle? I found AngularCompilerPlugin which may be helpful here but I'm not able to find any examples which would tell me what all is necessary to generate it successfuly. All previous attempts failed.

Here is the prototype to get some insight:
https://github.com/TomKubik/angular-host-app

"src" - the host app which loads the libraries (not so important here)

"projects/module-a/" is the one with lazy load module's attempts

Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate separate bundle by this webpack config:

```
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const path = require('path');

module.exports = { /* ... */
   externals: {
       "zone.js": "Zone",
       "rxjs": "rxjs",
    "@angular/core": "ng.core",
    "@angular/common": "ng.common",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "ng.platformBrowser",
    "@angular/elements": "ng.elements"
},
entry: {
    lazy: './src/app/page2/page2.module.ts',
},
resolve: {
    mainFields: ['browser', 'module', 'main']
},
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack'] },
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader', options: { minimize: true } },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: false
            }
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new AngularCompilerPlugin({
        skipCodeGeneration: true,
        tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.lazymodules.json',
        entryModule: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/app/page2/page2.module#Page2Module')
    })
],
mode: "production",
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/lazy',
    libraryTarget: "umd"
},
}
```

the most important part was to set **skipCodeGeneration: true** and then "**module**" option (from related tsconfig) to "**umd**".... otherwise it generates more or less "empty" file, just some js wrappers but real content was missing....

This is one way to generate actually some content in separate bundle, still not sure if the right one...